# Помогите с кодом распознавания человека на видео с помощью SVM и HOG (Opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

Я только начал программировать. У меня есть задача определить на видео машины. В библиотеке Opencv имеется стандартный метод getDefaultPeopleDetector определения людей. Вот код определения людей на фото:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
// загружаем тестовое изображение
Mat img = imread("1856.jpg");
// увеличиваем начальный масштаб изображения для
// поиска мелких объектов
resize(img, img, Size(2 * img.cols, 2 * img.rows));
// параметры HOG-дескриптора и детектора
int nbins = 9;
Size cellSize(8, 8);
Size blockSize(16, 16);
Size blockStride(8, 8);
Size winSize(64, 128);
Size winStride(4, 4);
// создаем HOG-дескриптор/детектор
HOGDescriptor hog(winSize, blockSize, blockStride, cellSize, nbins);
// устанавливаем в качестве модели
// линейную машину опорных векторов,
// соответствующую размеру окна детектирования 64x128.
hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
// проверяем соответствие количества коэффициентов
// гиперплоскости SVM и размера HOG-дескриптора
// одного окна детектирования
assert(hog.checkDetectorSize());
// производим детектирование
vector<Rect> locations;
vector<double> weights;
hog.detectMultiScale(img, locations, weights, 0.0, winStride, Size(), 1.05, 2., true);
// уменьшаем изображение до начальных размеров
resize(img, img, Size(img.cols / 2, img.rows / 2));
// отрисовываем срабатывания детектора на изображении
for (size_t i = 0; i < locations.size(); ++i)
{
    Rect detection = locations[i];
    detection.x /= 2;
    detection.y /= 2;
    detection.width /= 2;
    detection.height /= 2;
    rectangle(img, detection, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
}
// отображаем результат
namedWindow("detections");
imshow("detections", img);
waitKey();
destroyAllWindows();
return 0;
}
```

С переносом этого алгоритма на видео появились проблемы. Помогите, пожалуйста с этим.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните какие именно появились проблемы.

Comment: Когда пытаюсь выполнить этот алгоритм на каждом кадре видео выдается ошибка с памятью "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE298F7788 in SVM_HOG.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000E6CE95F500". Вот здесь я выделяю каждый кадр для дальнейшей работы:

Comment: int main()
{
 string filename = "Street.MP4";
 VideoCapture capture(filename);
 Mat frame;

 namedWindow("w", 1);
 for (; ; )
 {
  capture >> frame;
  if (frame.empty())
   break;
  Mat img;
  Mat framecopy = frame.clone();